# Assignment from incompatible pointer type after code compilation

Tags: c

I have been learning C programming lately and writing some codes. Below is a code I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){


    int num[] = {10, 15, 25, 30, 45, 10};
    char *names[][11] = {"Drew", "Larry Page", "Seggy", "Mark"};
    //int *ip, i = 0;
    char **ip;
    int *p, i = 0, j = 0;

    for (ip = names; *(ip + i); i++)
        printf("%s ", *(ip + i));
    printf("\n\n");

    for (p = num; j < sizeof(num)/sizeof(num[0]); j++)
        printf("%d ", *(p + j));
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I build and run the above code, I get my desired result. However I get this warning:

```
jdoodle.c:12:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     for (ip = names; *(ip + i); i++)
             ^
```

I have tested the code on various IDE's but get similar warning. Appreciate assistance.

Comment: Next time compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and you'd see *way more things to address*

Comment: also, in C instead of `*(ip + i)` we write `ip[i]` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
char *names[][11] = {"Drew", "Larry Page", "Seggy", "Mark"};
```

you don't want a 2d array of pointer to `char`, you want an array of pointer to `char`:

```
char *names[] = {"Drew", "Larry Page", "Seggy", "Mark"}; /* Don't hardcode 11 */
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @keine. Without 11, I get this segmentation error: `bash: line 1:     7 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) bash -c 'gcc -o jdoodle *.c && ./jdoodle' `

Comment: @Fokwa Best Check you for loop condition

Comment: @FokwaBest: `NULL`-terminate the pointer array: `char *names[] = {"Drew", "Larry Page", "Seggy", "Mark", NULL};`

Comment: Hi all. I have updated the for loop as `for (ip = names; i < sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]); i++)` and the error is gone. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

you want `char *names[11]` array of char pointers, not `char *names[][11]`.

Declare it like

```
char *names[] = {"Drew", "Larry Page", "Seggy", "Mark"};
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this warning is because `char *names[][11]` is of type  `char *[1][11]` and `char **ip` is of type `char **`.
Basically what you are doing is you are creating a 1x11 array of pointers to char(one row and 11 columns with 11 pointers).
Because there is no partial initialization in C, the first 4 pointers will point to the addresses of the static string literals in the read only memory, and the rest will be zeros.

The simplest way to get around the compiler warning and get the code working is to cast `ip = (char **)names` in the first for loop. It will work, because `ip` wants to point to the address of some pointer and what is `names` - it's basically the address of the first pointer in the array. Now when you dereference `ip` you will get the 4 pointers and will stop after `Mark`, because the fifth pointer will be 0.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){


int num[] = {10, 15, 25, 30, 45, 10};
char *names[][11] = {"Drew", "Larry Page", "Seggy", "Mark"};
//int *ip, i = 0;
char **ip;
int *p, i = 0, j = 0;

for (ip = (char** )names; *(ip + i); i++)
    printf("%s ", *(ip + i));
printf("\n\n");

for (p = num; j < sizeof(num)/sizeof(num[0]); j++)
    printf("%d ", *(p + j));
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Another simple way to get this working is to change to type of `char *names[][11]` to `char* (*ip)[11]` and modify the first for loop:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){


int num[] = {10, 15, 25, 30, 45, 10};
char *names[][11] = {"Drew", "Larry Page", "Seggy", "Mark"};
//int *ip, i = 0;
char* (*ip)[11];
int *p, i = 0, j = 0;

for (ip = names; ip[0][i]; i++)
    printf("%s ", ip[0][i]);
printf("\n\n");

for (p = num; j < sizeof(num)/sizeof(num[0]); j++)
    printf("%d ", *(p + j));
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

The two above solutions are obscured, and considered "hacks" by me. I suggest you to use one of the last two examples below.
Quick notes:

1. the compiler allows you to omit the first dimension size, because to calculate the offset of the array elements you need only the second size;
2. usually the compiler will issue a warning `warning: missing braces around initializer` if you enable the warnings with -Wall. So always use braces like so `char *names[][11] = {{"Drew", "Larry Page", "Seggy", "Mark"}};`

Apart from the simple explanation above, I assume you wanted somehow to store an array of strings and print them. 
There are a few ways to accomplish this:

1. make an array of pointers to strings - `char *names[] = {"Drew", "Larry Page", "Seggy", "Mark"};`, but this way you wouldn't be able to change the content of the strings, because all literal strings reside in the read only memory. That's why it's best to use the `const` qualifier to be more explicit you can't change the content(`const char *names[] = {"Drew", "Larry Page", "Seggy", "Mark"};`), if you don't use it then the compiler will allow you to change the content, but when the program executes it will generate segmentation fault, if you use `const` then the compiler will not let you even compile.
2. make a multidimensional array of strings - `char names[][11] = {{"Drew"}, {"Larry Page"}, {"Seggy"}, {"Mark"}};`. Here you have to be make sure you know the size of the strings. You can change the array contents here.

Here is the modified working version, no warnings, with multidimensional array:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){


int num[] = {10, 15, 25, 30, 45, 10};
char names[][11] = {{"Drew"}, {"Larry Page"}, {"Seggy"}, {"Mark"}};
//int *ip, i = 0;
char (*ip)[11];
int *p, i = 0, j = 0;

for (ip = names; i < sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]); i++)
    printf("%s ", *(ip + i));
printf("\n\n");

for (p = num; j < sizeof(num)/sizeof(num[0]); j++)
    printf("%d ", *(p + j));
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Here is the modified version with array of pointers to strings:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){


int num[] = {10, 15, 25, 30, 45, 10};
char *names[11] = {"Drew", "Larry Page", "Seggy", "Mark"};
//int *ip, i = 0;
char **ip;
int *p, i = 0, j = 0;

for (ip = names; *(ip + i); i++)
    printf("%s ", *(ip + i));
printf("\n\n");

for (p = num; j < sizeof(num)/sizeof(num[0]); j++)
    printf("%d ", *(p + j));
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

I have tried to modify the least your code. Further optimizations are still possible.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. For the second example, we can omit the size since we are initializing the array at the time of declaration. `char *names[]` and then in the for loop use `i < sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0])`

Comment: The size can me omitted, but I did not omit it, because I tried to modify the least your code. Note that your code remains the same, only the incorrect parts of it are corrected. There is no need to change the for loop condition, because there is no partial initialization in C and `names` will be populated with NULL pointers after the `Mark` string, thus the for loop will terminate as expected.

Comment: I have tested all of the examples and they are working as expected.